# Variable is unused one instance but not in another

Tags: java, string, swing, variables

I am writing a quadratic formula using JOptionPane rather than Scanner. One of the variables (lines 12 & 17, userInput) is marked undeclared creating a runtime error. The other iterations don't seem to have that problem. I am a beginner but I have tried using the resources at my disposal with little luck. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
/*

*/
package a3main2;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class A3main2 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String userInput;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hooray for quadratic fun!");
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the value for 'a': ");
        Double a = Double.parseDouble(userInput);
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the value for 'b': ");
        Double b = Double.parseDouble(userInput);
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the value for 'c': ");
        Double c = Double.parseDouble(userInput);

        Double discriminant = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(b , b))- (4 * a * c));
        Double part1 = ((-(b)) / (2 * a));
        Double x = ((-(b)) + Math.sqrt(discriminant) / (2 * a));
        Double y = ((-(b)) - Math.sqrt(discriminant) / (2 * a));

        if (discriminant < 0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The two roots are " + x + "i" + 
                    " and " + y + "i.");
        }          
        else if (discriminant > 0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are two roots: " + x + 
                    " and " + y + ".");
        }
        else if (discriminant == 0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is only one root: " + x + 
                    ".");
        }
        else if (a == 0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is only one root: " + part1 
            + ".");
        }
        System.exit(0);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Note also that `System.exit(0);
        }` should be `System.exit(0);` ..

Answer (score 3):

You need to do

```
userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the value for 'a': ");
Double a = Double.parseDouble(userInput);
```

On all the different cases where input is entered.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I feel like such a novice so I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

all variables declared within a method need to be initialized before you can use them, cause they do not have default values (like class members).

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `userInput` stays null.

You should save the user input in the userInput variable, try this:

```
userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the value for 'a': ");
```